# I want to get access to only one item of an array after mapping

Tags: json, reactjs, flask

I want to compare an input with my data array that I got from fetching a json file. But I only wanna compare the first item. I cant do it like this:

```
if (this.state.passedInputName == this.state.data.c.company_name) {
        console.log("input Name is equal to Database Name")}
```

because I would get the error:"TypeError: Cannot read property 'company_name' of undefined"

so I tried it with this code:

```
  if (this.state.passedInputName == this.state.data.map((item) => (item.c.company_name))) {
    console.log("input Name is equal to Database Name")}
```

and this doesn't work if there's more than one company, because he would compare the input name to more than one company name. But I only wanna compare the first company name to the input. 
Is there anything that I can use with `this.state.data.map` that I only get access to the first company name? I dont know how else I could compare the Input with the data, because it seems that I only have access to attributes from the data throught `map` the data.

Comment: I think you can try this way `if (this.state.passedInputName == this.state.data[0].c.company_name)`  or   `if (this.state.passedInputName === this.state.data[0].c.company_name)`

Comment: If it helps you then tick/vote the answer will help others to findout solution for same problem

Comment: can't vote because I got less than 15 reputations

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this way

```
if (this.state.passedInputName == this.state.data[0].c.company_name)
```

or

```
if (this.state.passedInputName === this.state.data[0].c.company_name)
```